# pathlib File directory (not working) but without the file name (Parent returns two directories up)

Tags: python, pathlib

If Im in:
C:\dir\pythonfile.py

when I run Path.cwd()
I worry about terminal runs from different places, so (maybe wrong) I rely on Path(**file**)

that returns the right path with the file. If I use ".parent" I get:
dir = Path(**file**).parent # returns C:\ NOT C:\dir\

Im stuck. Help?

Edit: If I run
resolve; same problem

Comment: You are in `C:\dir` and do a `.parent()` then you are in `C:\\`

Answer (score 0):

`Path(file)` returns the directory the file is in (`C:\dir` in your case). `Path(file).parent` returns the parent of the directory, not of the file; this is `C:\`. Just use `dir = Path(file)`.